# Linear dependence and independence solution. How was it found?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text:

[image]

I feel like my text skipped a step to find the coefficients/solutions. Did they write a system of linear equations and use Gaussian elimination? How did they do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see whether these vectors are dependent examine the system:
 $a(1,3,1)+b(0,1,2)+c(1,0,-5)=(0,0,0)$

which is equivalent with

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & -5
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

then you can use elimination to find $a,b,c$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & -5
\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -3\\
1 & 2 & -5
\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -3\\
0 & 2 & -6
\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -3\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

So the above system is equivalent to the following

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -3\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} a+c=0 \\ b-3c=0 \end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} a=-c \\ b=3c \end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-c\\
3c\\
c
\end{pmatrix}=c\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
3\\
1
\end{pmatrix} $$

And we can choose $c=1$ so $(a,b,c)=(-1,3,1)$

Comment: can you show me?

Comment: @Jwan622 show you what?

Comment: Elimination. Can you show me steps?

Comment: @Jwan622 I edited my answer

Comment: Oh I see, your solution is just a single example of a solution here. The text has a whole other solution.

Answer (score 1):

They found that you can express one vector as a linear combination of the others, in your case:

$$(1,3,1)=3\cdot (0,1,2)+(1,0,-5)$$

Thus, you can rearrange the equation to form

$$\mathbf0=3\cdot (0,1,2)+(1,0,-5)-(1,3,1)$$

which is a non-trivial linear combination of $\mathbf0$, i.e. the set is per definition linearly dependent.

I guess that this relation was found by inspection. In general, eyeballing the vectors can often help to find such trivial cases and shorten your argument. However, for being sure you can always perform Gaussian elimination on the three vectors to find a maybe elusive combination.

---

Note that the definition

> A set $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}\subseteq V$ for a vector space $V$ is linearly independent if $$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_is_i=\mathbf0$$ has only the trivial solution $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_n=0$.

is equivalent with the formulation that you can not express any $s_j$ as a linear combination of the others, as you may always rearrange the resulting equation as above.

Comment: (+1) You were too fast for me…

Comment: Cheers. You're normally too fast for me @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: I still don't get how they found the coefficients from the vector equation.

Comment: @Jwan622 As I've said, probably just through eyeballing, e.g. considering that you have to have one contribution from $(1,0,-5)$ to create $(1,3,1)$ as the other vector with $0$ in its first component can not contribute anything there. Similar, for the second argument reversed. Then they just found that the last contribution fits on both sides. This way of thinking about linear dependence is not at all formal, obviously, but this intuitive approach might lead you to a result in a short time.

Comment: Can you show me steps using elimination?

Comment: @Jwan622 Why do want to see the steps of elimination? As a tip: for little integer problems elimination will sometimes cost you more time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the book skipped some step or the Authors have find that by inspection which sometimes is possible for simple cases, here we have

$$v_1=3v_2+v_3 \iff 1\cdot v_1-3\cdot v_2-1\cdot v_3=0$$

More in general, yes we need gaussian elimination to find the coefficients which leads to non trivial solutions for $A\vec c=0$.